# Mongoose reacting differently to presence of callbacks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

I was debugging a chunk of my Mongoose queries that I wanted to execute one after another to avoid inconsistency. After lot of trial, errors and tests, I finally stumbled upon a solution that seemed to work.

In one query, I include a query and in another, I skip including the callback function. The *callback* I am referring to is seen in the syntax of a `Model.findByIdAndUpdate` statement.

`Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, [update], [options], [***callback***])`

The one which has a callback function executes perfectly and the one which doesn't, doesn't execute. It's encapsulated in a function which returns a mongoose promsise.

Here is the first query with the schema in Robomongo which adds an 'organiser' successfully:

```
function addUserToHackathonOrganisers(userId, hackathonId) {
    return Hackathon.findOneAndUpdate(
        {hackathonId: hackathonId},
        {$addToSet: {organisers: userId.toString()}},
        {new: true}
    );
}
```

Notice *organisers Array[0]* which indicates no update.
[image]

Now, here is the query that works (with the callback in). In the attached image, you can see the *organisers Array[1]* which indicates that its updated.

```
function addUserToHackathonOrganisers(userId, hackathonId) {
    return Hackathon.findOneAndUpdate(
        {hackathonId: hackathonId},
        {$addToSet: {organisers: userId.toString()}},
        {new: true},
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

[image]

I'm clueless why this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Suggestions for a better title are welcome, btw :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** method without a callback option returns a [`Query`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js), it does not execute but the one with a callback executes hence why you see an update with the callback and none without.

From the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate):

```
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback)   // executes
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options)             // returns Query
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback)            // executes
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update)                      // returns Query
A.findOneAndUpdate()                                        // returns Query
```

---

If you had written the function as

```
function addUserToHackathonOrganisers(userId, hackathonId) {
    return Hackathon.findOneAndUpdate(
        {hackathonId: hackathonId},
        {$addToSet: {organisers: userId.toString()}},
        {new: true}
    ).exec(); // chaining exec() to a Query returns a Promise
}
```

then when you call it, it executes and returns a promise, e.g.

```
var promise = addUserToHackathonOrganisers(userId, hackathonId);
promise.then(function(addedUser){
    console.log(addedUser); // shows the updated user
});
```

---

### UPDATE

To address your [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761698/mongoose-reacting-differently-to-presence-of-callbacks/43762404?noredirect=1#comment74567089_43762404) in the comments, the callback in the [promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)'s `then()` method

```
promise.then(function(addedUser){
    console.log(addedUser); // shows the updated user
});
```

is just the same as the callback in the **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)** option except that instead of two arguments, the promise handles the arguments separately with the error argument caught in the promise's `catch()` method:

```
promise.then(function(addedUser){
    console.log(addedUser); // shows the updated user
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

For more details, refer to the docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. That explains a lot :D

Comment: Just to clarify, the callback from the promise `function(addedUser)` is different from the callback of the mongoDb execution right? Or they are the same? Like I can add `function(err, docs)`. I was wanting to `return function(err, docs)` as the promise callback actually (Not sure if that makes sense?)

Comment: Also, *WHEN* do I use `.exec()`? Just whenever I have an update statment and want to return a promise?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated :)